# How to delete a table from Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I've been experimenting with Google Cloud Spanner and accidentally made a table with a less than ideal primary key - it resulted in sequential inserts that quickly started eating up CPU. There were a large number of inserts happening when it froze so I decided to delete the offending table and recreate it in hopes that the new schema design would improve performance. After I delete the table the Spanner instance CPU drops to ~5% (seems like a baseline).

WOW! Was I surprised to find that when I remade a table with the same name after deleting the offending table, Spanner quickly restarted the workload it was doing before and reached 100% CPU almost immediately. A preview of the data in the Web UI also showed all of the data from the old table as well.

Even after I waited 45 minutes to try recreating the table Spanner continued to "pick up" where it had left off before.

Is my best bet to just make a new table with a different name? Is there a way around this or a different amount of time I should wait?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner may still be keeping a reference to the older version of the table and all of its data while the inserts are happening. The actual result in this case is not well defined since the table to be deleted is in an inconsistent state. In general, it's not a good idea to drop tables, columns, indexes with reads and/or writes.

Since you are just trying to run experiments, you can just create a new database and point your application to the same.